# How can I remove the automatically generated string after '?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In production mode, extra random numbers are always shown in url when it's showing the path to the image uploaded.

iIt's something like this

**view**

```
http://example.com<%=  commynity.image_url %>
```

**html**

```
http://example.com/images/576/34/sample.jpg?473373516
```

Comment: might be important to keep the numbers.. they prevent the image from being cached..is that the aim?

Comment: @Amitd Thanks! good to know that. What's gonna happen if user want to use its thumbnail in other sites?  the image url with radom number won'r be recognizeble

Comment: for a browser its always a url with or without the number..browsers think it as a different url if number keep changing..so the image doesnt get cached.

Comment: @Amitd Thanks so it won't affect to server but user's client PC. am I right?

Comment: nope not really.. but it will just add a new request from client every time you need to load the image from the client.( but if your image keeps changing better to have the random number in there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
http://example.com<%=  commynity.image_url.split("?")[0] %>
```